# Convert MERGE to UPDATE

Tags: oracle, sql-update, sql-merge

I have the following `MERGE` statement.Is there a way to convert this into an update statement without using `MERGE`?

```
MERGE INTO tab1
USING (SELECT tab1.col1, tab2.col2
         FROM tab1, tab2
        WHERE tab1.col1 = tab2.col1) tab3
   ON (tab1.col1 = tab3.col1)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET col2 = tab3.col2
```

Comment: The feature is called [Updatable Join View](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30) - see in the link the restrictions and the documentation

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - an `update` statement is not a view.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking about is called "update through join", and contrary to a widely held belief, it is possible in Oracle. But there is a catch.

Obviously, the update - no matter how you attempt to perform it - is not well defined unless column `col1` is unique in table `tab2`. That column is used for lookup in the update process; if its values are not unique, the update will be ambiguous. I ignore here idiotic retorts such as "uniqueness is needed only for those values also found in `tab1.col1`", or "there is no ambiguity as long as all values in `tab2.col2` are equal when the corresponding values in `tab2.col1` are equal".

The "catch" is this. The uniqueness of `tab2.col1` may be a matter of data (you know it when you inspect the data), or a matter of metadata (there is a unique constraint, or a unique index, or a PK constraint, etc., on `tab2.col1`, which the parser can inspect without ever looking at the actual data).

`merge` will work even when uniqueness is only known by inspecting the data. It will still throw an error if uniqueness is violated - but that will be a runtime error (only after the data in `tab2` is accessed from disk). By contrast, updating through a join requires the same uniqueness to be known ahead of time, through the metadata (or in other ways: for example if the second rowset - not a table but the table-like result of a query - is the result of an aggregation grouping on the join column; then the uniqueness is guaranteed by the definition of "aggregation").

Here is a brief example to show the difference.

Test data:

```
create table tab1 (col1 number, col2 number);
insert into tab1 (col1, col2) values (1, 3);

create table tab2 (col1 number, col2 number);
insert into tab2 (col1, col2) values (1, 6);

commit;
```

`merge` statement (with check at the end):

```
merge into tab1
using(
select tab1.col1,
       tab2.col2
from tab1,tab2 
where tab1.col1 = tab2.col1) tab3
on(tab1.col1 = tab3.col1)
when matched then
update 
set col2 = tab3.col2;

1 row merged.

select * from tab1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          6
```

Now let's restore table `tab1` to its original data for the next test(s):

```
rollback;

select * from tab1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          3
```

Update through join - with no uniqueness guaranteed in the metadata (will result in error):

```
update
  ( select t1.col2 as t1_c2, t2.col2 as t2_c2
    from   tab1 t1 join tab2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
  )
set t1_c2 = t2_c2; 

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

Now let's add a `unique` constraint on the lookup column:

```
alter table tab2 modify (col1 unique);

Table TAB2 altered.
```

and try the update again (with the **same** `update` statement), plus verification:

```
update
  ( select t1.col2 as t1_c2, t2.col2 as t2_c2
    from   tab1 t1 join tab2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
  )
set t1_c2 = t2_c2; 

1 row updated.

select * from tab1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          6
```

So - you **can** do it, if you use the correct syntax (as I have shown here) **AND** - very important - you have a unique or PK constraint or a unique index  on column `tab2.col1`.